# How use setTimeout() with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

How can I use setTimeout() in a Backbone model?
I have the next code:

```
var ContentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
URL: "http://localhost/example.php",    
requestType: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: "", //Set the value outside the model

startSend: function (Data) { 
           //
},
reply: function (Data) { 
    var dataJson = eval(Data);              
    console.log(dataJson);
    setTimeout(this.ajaxRequest(),4000);
},
problems: function (Data) { 
    //
},
ajaxRequest: function () {
    $.ajax({
        async:true,
        type: this.requestType,
        dataType: this.dataType, 
        url: this.URL,
        data: this.data,
        beforeSend:this.startSend,
        success: this.reply,
        timeout:4000,
        error:this.problems 
    });

}
```

});

Alternatively I have tried:

```
setTimeout(function(){
               //ajax code
               },4000);
```

But the result is the same. setTimeout() don't work. The request only run once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A couple of things are amiss. First off, this line:

```
setTimeout(this.ajaxRequest(),4000);
```

Should be:

```
setTimeout(this.ajaxRequest, 4000);
```

The first line of code executes the ajaxRequest function and passes the result (which is `undefined`) to setTimeout. That means the `ajaxRequest` function will execute once, but too soon. The latter line does what you want, which is to pass the function *itself* to setTimeout, and `ajaxRequest` will be called 4 seconds later.

But that's not quite enough. When the `ajaxRequest` function is executed, the value of `this` context is incorrect. When you called setTimeout, the context of the callback is set to `window`. You can verify this by `console.log(this)` in the callback function.

To fix it, you need to **bind** the context of the function. Since you're using Backbone, you've also got underscore.js already loaded. Using [_.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) oughta do it:

```
setTimeout(_.bind(this.ajaxRequest, this), 4000);
```

**Edit**:

Come to think of it, there might be another problem. When the ajax call succeeds or fails, the `reply` or `problems` functions may suffer from the same loss of context as `ajaxRequest` did. But if there is, it's easily fixed.

Instead of calling `_.bind` on those too, the simplest way is to call [_.bindAll](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) in your Backbone model constructor.

```
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'ajaxRequest', 'reply', 'problems');
}
```

When you call `_.bindAll`, underscore guarantees that every time any of the listed methods of your model is called, the `this` context variable points to the model itself, unless specifically bound to something else.

Comment: Thanks for reponse. I have understood the explication, with _.bindAll the code works but not with _bind in setTimeout

Comment: @vicenrele - you're welcome. If the problem is solved, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi @fencliff! Do yo Know why the next code not work? `setTimeout(function(){ 
 this.ajaxRequest;
},4000);` But yes the next one: `setTimeout(this.timeoutFunction,4000)`

Comment: Also, I've tried this:
`timeoutFunction: function(){
 this.ajaxRequest;
},`

`setTimeout(this.timeoutFunction,4000);` but not work

Comment: @vicenrele It's because inside the anonymous `setTimeout` callback function `this` refers to `window`, not your class. Use `_.bind(func, this)` if you need to ensure the context is kept, and if there's more problems, consider opening another question.

Comment: Ok. I will open another question. Thanks

Comment: @vicenrele, I don't really understand what you mean. Maybe open (yet) another question?

Comment: I tried to use the suggestion:

`initialize: function() { _.bindAll(this); }`

...but it did not work due to this error:

`bindAll must be passed function names`

To fix that, I ended up using:

`initialize: function() { _.bindAll.apply(_, [this].concat(_.functions(this))); },`

Comment: @Zahnon, looks like the function names became required parameters in underscore `1.5.0`. This answer was given before that release. Edited my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special to use `setTimeout` with backbone.  Check the scope of `this` in your `reply` function.  My guess it that `this.ajaxRequest()` isn't in scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setInverval` instead.

```
setInterval(this.ajaxRequest, 4000);
```

`setTimeout` Triggers the function once.

`setInterval` Triggers each `n` ms.

```
var interval = setInterval(this.ajaxRequest, 4000);
```

`clearInterval` used to clear `setInterval`.

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Or pass the context parameter on your `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    context: this,
    ...
});
```

Comment: Well, actually he does define `this.reply` as the success callback to the ajax request, which will trigger the method again.

Comment: What happens when the Ajax call returns successfully?

Comment: Nothing will happen, because the `this` context is incorrect. `this` in `setTimeout` callbacks is window, unless bound to something else.

Comment: @fencliff I agree (see my answer)

Comment: @fencliff, My intention is that a loop of setTimeout() was run when a view with this model in a collection was created, and setTimeout() not run if the model is removed of the collection. I have this code to remove the model: this.model.collection.remove(this.model); But setTimeout() doesn't stop working. Why?

Comment: @vicenrele, maybe open another question and include a bit more information and sample code? It's a bit hard to understand from that short explanation what you mean.